# Run Nodejs command when file saved

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to automaticly run a command: `npm something.js` when I save the `something.js` file?
Thanks.

Comment: have you looked at the npm watch package?

Comment: you can use nodemon

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could also checkout [onchange](https://www.npmjs.com/package/onchange):

```
npm install -g onchange
```

You can use it to trigger something upon saving a file:

```
onchange app.js -- node app.js
```

I use it to autoexecute files that I'm working on, for example.